# Interchanging selected rows and columns and plot a spaghetti plot of a R dataframe

Tags: r, coding-style, interchange

I have a R dataframe like this:

| Year | Country | Car | Bike | Truck |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | US | 4342 | 5783 | 5849 |
| 2011 | US | 8292 | 4304 | 4839 |
| 2012 | US | 5839 | 5930 | 8483 |

I need to plot a spaghetti plot for all three types(car,bike,truck) for US. That is: Type as the legend. I understand that I need to interchange columns of Types to rows. But I am unable to do that with out interchanging Year.

In a nutshell, I think I need this kind of table to plot the spaghetti plot.

| Year | Type | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | US | XXXX |
| 2010 | US | XXXX |
| 2010 | US | XXXX |
| 2011 | US | XXXX |
| 2011 | US | XXXX |
| 2011 | US | XXXX |
| 2012 | US | XXXX |
| 2012 | US | XXXX |
| 2012 | US | XXXX |

Please help!

Comment: My tables are not showing somehow

Comment: Look up `pivot_longer()`